# sql inner join over multiple tables

Tags: sql, inner-join

I've given this relational scheme and following task:

> Inner Join: Return a list of professors, which gives
>   'lehrveranstaltung' of the 'fachbereich' with the name 'informatik'.
>   * print 'vorname', 'ho_name', 'lv_name'
>   * output should sort surnames in ascending order and if they're the same in descending order
>   * identical lines should online shown once

[image]

now I came up with following query:

```
select distinct
    v.vorname,
    h.ho_name,
    l.lv_name
    --print wanted, only once
from
    vorname v,
    hochschulangehoeriger h,
    lehrveranstaltung l
    -- from these tables
    inner join fachbereich f on f.fb_name = 'Informatik'
    -- only the 'informatik' events
    inner join prof_haelt_lv on l.lv_nr = pl.lv_nr
    -- make sure 'lehrveranstaltung' is from a professor
    inner join mitarbeiter mit on pl.pers_Nr = mit.pers_Nr
    -- make sure dude is a prof
where
    mit.ho_nr = h.ho_nr
    and
    mit.ho_nr = v.ho_nr -- give only names from prof
order by
    2 asc,
    3 desc; -- order rules
```

I think this works for me (can't test it properly). But when I look at it I'll wish that I came up for a bether solution since this looks kinda ugly and wrong for me.

Is there a bether way of doing this? (Have to use inner join)

Comment: Your query is mixing old-style JOINs (`FROM x, y WHERE x.a = y.a`) with modern-style JOINs (`x INNER JOIN y ON x.a = y.a`). You should stick to only using the modern style of JOIN.

Comment: You also don't need to alias every table - your query would probably be more readable without aliasing.

Comment: 1. sqlfiddle.com 2. Your comments add nothing. Omit. 3. ORDER BY column number is deprecated. Names. 4. INNER is noise. Omit.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the table you have, you may use the following SQL statement

```
SELECT DISTINCT v.vorname,
       h.ho_name,
       l.lv_name
  FROM vorname v
 INNER JOIN hochschulangehoeriger h
    ON v.ho_nr = h.ho_nr
 INNER JOIN mitarbeiter m
    ON m.ho_nr = h.ho_nr
 INNER JOIN fachbereich f
    ON f.fb_nr = m.fb_nr
   AND f.fb_name = 'Informatik'
 INNER JOIN lehrveranstaltung l
    ON l.fb_nr = f.nb_nr
 INNER JOIN professor p
    ON p.pers_nr = m.pers_nr
 INNER JOIN prof_haelt_lv pl
    ON pl.pers_nr = p.pers_nr
   AND pl.lv_nr = l.lv_nr
 ORDER BY 2, 
          3 DESC;
```

Also, these section on your SQL, this has no connection to any table in your SQL

```
inner join fachbereich f on f.fb_name = 'Informatik'
-- only the 'informatik' events
```

you forgot the alias for prof_haelt_lv

```
inner join prof_haelt_lv on l.lv_nr = pl.lv_nr
-- make sure 'lehrveranstaltung' is from a professor
```